# Get result in single row

Tags: sql, group-by

I am querying on table below.

[image: Table view]

```
SELECT [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo]
    ,Count(*) AS TotalNoOfTasks
    ,[Status]
FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
GROUP BY [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo]
    ,[Status]
```

and here is my result set

[image: result set against my group by query]

but problem is that i want to get result for each [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo] in following way

```
     | RiskUniqueIdentificationNo | | TotalNoOfTasks |  | InProgressTask | | ClosedTask |
     ------------ ------------  ------------ ------------------------- ------------------
     |             1              | |        3       |  |        2       | | 1|
```

i have tried to do some thing like this

```
SELECT [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo]
    ,Count(*) AS TotalNoOfTasks
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [Status] = 'Closed'
            THEN COUNT([Status])
        ELSE 0
        END AS ClosedTasks
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [Status] != 'Closed'
            AND [EndDate] < GETDATE()
            THEN COUNT([Status])
        ELSE 0
        END AS OverdueTasks
FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
GROUP BY [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo]
    ,[Status]
```

but can't succeeded. I need help that how can i accomplish this.

Comment: Remove Status from GROUP BY. Move case into aggregation.

Comment: @jarlh When i remove [Status] from group by clause i get following error "column 'dbo.Tasks.Status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: you have to remove it from the select statement as well. Based on your stated desired output this should not be a problem for you? As jarl suggested, the CASE statement needs to be moved into the aggregation section

Comment: @ADyson , i was missing second point. Actually culprit was case outside the aggregation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove status from `GROUP BY` and do a `COUNT` using `CASE`.

```
SELECT [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo],
       COUNT(1) AS TotalNoOfTasks,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status]<> 'Closed' THEN 1 END) AS InProgressTask,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status]= 'Closed' THEN 1 END) AS ClosedTask
FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
GROUP BY [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move to conditional aggregation as below

```
Select [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo],
       Count(*) as TotalNoOfTasks, 
       sum(case when [Status] = 'In progress' then 1 else 0 end) [InProgressTask],
       sum(case when [Status] = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) [ClosedTask] 
from [dbo].[Tasks]
group by [RiskUniqueIdentificationNo]
```